# R: Create new column in dataframe from existing columns using conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe with two numeric columns that I'd like to use to create and populate a third column using conditions.

Here is an example of my dataframe:

| - | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 134 |
| 2 | 343 | NA |
| 3 | 123 | 145 |
| 4 | NA | 243 |
| 5 | NA | NA |
| 6 | NA | 293 |

I'd like to create a new column based upon the values in columns A and B and these conditions:

- If there is a value in column A, I would like that value in column C
- If column A contains NA and column B contains a value, I'd like that value in column C
- If neither columns contains a value, I'd like a NA in column C

Example output:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 134 | 123 |
| 2 | 343 | NA | 342 |
| 3 | 123 | 145 | 123 |
| 4 | NA | 243 | 243 |
| 5 | NA | NA | NA |
| 6 | NA | 293 | 243 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(C = case_when(
    !is.na(A) ~ A,
    is.na(A) & !is.na(B) ~ B,
    is.na(A) & is.na(B) ~ NA_integer_
  ))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Rowwise: 
      A     B     C
  <int> <int> <int>
1   123   134   123
2   343    NA   343
3   123   145   123
4    NA   243   243
5    NA    NA    NA
6    NA   293   293
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(A = c(123L, 343L, 123L, NA, NA, NA), B = c(134L, 
NA, 145L, 243L, NA, 293L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `coalesce`

```
df1 <- df1 %>% 
    mutate(C = coalesce(A, B))
```

-output

```
df1
#   A   B   C
#1 123 134 123
#2 343  NA 343
#3 123 145 123
#4  NA 243 243
#5  NA  NA  NA
#6  NA 293 293
```

---

Or using `fcoalesce` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, C := fcoalesce(A, B)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- 
structure(list(A = c(123L, 343L, 123L, NA, NA, NA), B = c(134L, 
NA, 145L, 243L, NA, 293L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```